# How to merge two "Byval target as range"

Tags: excel, vba

Hope you can assist me on how it is possible to merge these two macros into one? Both Macros work fine independently but when i try to merge them one of them stops working. i have tried so many things but none of them seem to work.

The first macro is shown below and automatically inserts and copy the above row when the user click a specific range of cells. Furthermore columns width is automatically adjusted and formatting for a column is changed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
    If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("E15:E45")) Is Nothing Then
    With Selection
    .EntireRow.Copy
    .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown

End With
    End If

       'Automatically autofit columns when changes
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Load").Range("F:N").EntireColumn.AutoFit

    'Format columns 9 (I) as TEXT
    Columns(9).NumberFormat = "@"


End Sub
```

The second macro automatically inserts company name and project name in two columns when end users inserts the project code. Hence, it is a basically an automated lookup insert.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range

    If Not Intersect(Range("H:H"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In Intersect(Range("H:H"), Target)
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            If cell <> "" Then Call macro2(cell)
        Next cell
    End If
End Sub

Sub macro2(T As Range): Dim F As Range, w2 As Worksheet
Set w2 = Sheets("Lookups")
Set F = w2.Range("H:H").Find(T.Value, , , xlWhole)
If Not F Is Nothing Then
T.Offset(0, 1) = F.Offset(0, 1)
T.Offset(0, -1) = F.Offset(0, 2)
Else: T.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3: T.Offset(0, 1) = ""
End If
End Sub
```

Hope you can help :)

Comment: First of all, you are speaking about two different Worksheet events with different triggers. So it would be nice if you specify some other points: 1. How do you want to combine them (what should a combined macro do)? 2. Which of these events should run that macro? 3. In your `Sub macro2(T As Range)` you assign a certain sheet to variable, but it's still unknown which sheet those events belong to.

Comment: I would like both macros to be enabled at the same time since they should be triggered by changes in the target range(E14:E45) and ("H:H"). From what i know it is only possible to create 1 "change" macro. Hence, the need for combining both macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here is that the first one functions on `Worksheet_SelectionChange` and the second on `Worksheet_Change`. These both have different functionality, meaning the first macro fires when you click a cell, the second when a cell is changed.

This leads to the issue that if you merge the second into the first macro, it will fire once you click out of a cell (or press `Enter` etc.) and the macro will run on the cell selected after your action. So if you click an empty cell, it will fire, detect the cell is empty, and do nothing. Then when you click out of it, it will fire on the new cell, and leave the just changed cell untouched. Either way, it won't process properly.

One way to get around this (I'm sure there are more elegant ways) is to store the last selected cell in a public variable, and have the second sub run with the last selected cell from this variable, instead of the currently selected cell:

```
Option Explicit
Public lastcell As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error Resume Next

    If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("E15:E45")) Is Nothing Then
        With Selection
            .EntireRow.Copy
            .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
        End With
    End If

    'Automatically autofit columns when changes
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Load").Range("F:N").EntireColumn.AutoFit

    'Format columns 9 (I) as TEXT
    Columns(9).NumberFormat = "@"
    Dim cell As Range

    'if no last cell exists (at opening of workbook) use current cell instead.
    If lastcell Is Nothing Then
        Set lastcell = Target
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Range("H:H"), lastcell) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In Intersect(Range("H:H"), lastcell)
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            If cell <> "" Then Call macro2(cell)
        Next cell
    End If

    'Store current cell as last cell
    Set lastcell = Target

End Sub
```